# Delete records in report object

Tags: data-loader, workbench

I have 100 records in report object.tried multiple options like data loader, work bench and developer console to delete those 100 records but unable to delete those records.Could someone help??

Comment: Do you know the reports you want to delete?

Answer (score 1):

The `Report` sObject is [read-only](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_report.htm) because Reports are metadata. You cannot delete them with the REST API or with DML statements.

You will need to use a client of the Metadata API to perform a [destructive deployment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy_deleting_files.htm). This can be achieved with Workbench, Salesforce DX, Ant, or your client of choice.

Comment: also vendor devops products like Gearset, Blue Canvas, Copado can do this with nice UX